# Automatic separation between consonants and vowels in speech recording

Tags: python, signal-processing, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, audio-processing

Given an audio file of speech, (for example the file you can download from [here](https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features/blob/master/english.wav)), that looks like this:

[image: this]

If we examine it we will find that the **vowels** are the areas with the **largest amplitude**, and the **consonants** are the areas with the **small amplitude**.

How can you to **split** the consonants and vowels, as shown in the following image:

[image]

The `red` line is a `threshold`, what is below it is considered a small amplitude and belongs to **consonants**, and what is above it is considered a **vowel** because it has a large amplitude.

The `green` lines indicate where the large amplitude ends and the small one begins or vice versa.

Can you find all the places of the green lines?

```
# In[]
import numpy as np
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y, sr = librosa.load('english.wav', mono=True)

threshold = 0.2

# how to split ?
for s in y:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to segmenting into consonants and vowels would be to use a phoneme recognizer model, and then categorize the phonemes as consonant/not.
Here is complete example code for doing this using [allosaurus](https://github.com/xinjli/allosaurus) and [panphon](https://github.com/dmort27/panphon).

Imports

```py
import pandas
import numpy
import librosa

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import librosa.display

import allosaurus.app
import panphon
```

The segmentation

```py
def parse_timestamp_output(output):
    records = []
    lines = output.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        tok = line.split(' ')
        start = float(tok[0])
        duration = float(tok[1])
        end = start + duration
        label = tok[2]
        records.append(dict(start=start, end=end, label=label))
    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(records)
    return df

def is_consonant(ipa):
    ft = panphon.FeatureTable()
    cons = ft.word_fts(ipa)[0] >= {'cons': 1}
    return cons

def phone_recognize_file(path, emit=1.2, lang='eng'):

    model = allosaurus.app.read_recognizer()
    out = model.recognize(path, lang, timestamp=True, emit=emit)
    
    phones = parse_timestamp_output(out)
    phones['consonant'] = phones['label'].apply(is_consonant)
    phones['color'] = phones['consonant'].replace({True: 'green', False: 'red'})
    return phones

path = './english.wav'
phones = phone_recognize_file(path)
phones.head()
```

Will output a pandas.DataFrame like

```
   start    end   label consonant
0   0.42    0.465   h   True    
1   0.51    0.555   ə   False   
2   0.57    0.615   l   True    
3   0.66    0.705   o   False   
4   0.75    0.795   w   False
```

Here is a plot that shows the output on your example file.

[image]

The complete code, including plotting, can be found in https://github.com/jonnor/machinehearing/blob/master/handson/consonant-vowel-segmentation/Allosaurus.ipynb